# Using JRebel to swap the bytecode of a class

Tags: java, classloader, hotswap, jrebel

As said, I'd like to change the bytecode during execution. 
I am not running any sort of application or web server, it's just for a command line program.

Of course I could just create a new ClassLoader, but that's not feasible from the performance point of view.

I ran into JRebel, which should be capable of exactly this things, but I cannot find any examples, tutorial to archive this.

Java Hotswap is not an option, because it cannot deal with multiple Classloaders

Simple example to demonstrate what I want:

```
Class Car
{
   public void print() { System.out.println("I am Type A"); }
}
```

First I wanna load class `Car`:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
```

Do some stuff

```
myCar.print();  // => I am Type A
```

Change the source code

```
sourceCode.replace("Type A", "Type b");
```

Recompile and **change the byte code** in the **same classloader**

Execute same class again

```
myCar.print(); // => I am Type B
```

Hope I made my point clear.

Comment: I looking for a function like: jrebel.change("car", myClassloader, newByteCode[]);

Answer (score 1):

JRebel swaps the bytes for you after you recompile, you do not have to call an API to achieve that.

Comment: I do not wanna use jrebel with an application server etc. There wont be any .class files on the filesystem. I just need the functionality to swap byte code in memory

Comment: that would require some extra code writing indeed. I think SDK could help here http://www.zeroturnaround.com/resources/jrebel-plugins/